# Use of jQWidgets in React.js

Tags: reactjs, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I am new to React and want to use the `jQWidgets` library:

https://www.jqwidgets.com/reactjs-components-documentation/

So, using this link I setup `package.json`, created the folders `jqwidgets-react` and `jqwidgets` and put required **.js** file as given by them 
https://www.jqwidgets.com/reactjs-components-documentation/documentation/create-react-app/index.htm?search=

Now when I go to my **app.js** file and import any file, it shows me "module not found" like this:

```
import JqxDateTimeInput from './jqwidgets-react/react_jqxdatetimeinput';
```

**Failed to compile.**

> Error in ./src/layouts/report_definition/step_one.js Module not found:
>   ./jqwidgets-react/react_jqxdatetimeinput in
>   /home/amit/identity_pp/src/layouts/report_definition
>
> @ ./src/layouts/report_definition/step_one.js 61:30-81

Answer (score 0):

First we need to install the Create React App globally, so we can have it's commands available:
npm install -g create-react-app

Create a Create React App application:
create-react-app my-app

Integrating jQWidgets React Components
In the src folder add an assets folder with the jqwidgets and the jqwidgets-react folders inside of it:

Finally inside App.js file write your widget code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import JqxDateTimeInput from './assets/jqwidgets-react/react_jqxdatetimeinput';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>My First jQWidgets React Component</h4>
                <JqxDateTimeInput width={200} height={30} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```